# How do I join two tables, then insert into a third table with a NEW primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the statement I have now:

```
INSERT INTO jobs 
SELECT * 
FROM proposals 
JOIN commissions 
   ON proposals.commission_id = commissions.job_id 
WHERE proposals.proposal_id = '123'
```

It's working fine but is creating some primary key conflicts.  So, what I would like to do when the new row is entered, is this:

new primary key + commissions table data + proposals table data

Any ideas?

Comment: post your table structures

Comment: How should your new primary key be constructed? or do you not care?

Comment: Auto incriminate.

Comment: Auto incriminate - beloved by totalitarian regimes , instead of select * select named columns and create an auto_increment column in the new table.

Comment: Hahahahaha. Sorry about the typo. But yes, how do I do that, is what I’m trying to ask.

Comment: Then the rest of my last comment applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

then if you have auto increment pk , do this :

```
INSERT INTO jobs ( [list of columns except the auto increment column])
SELECT ( [list of columns accordingly])
FROM proposals 
JOIN commissions 
   ON proposals.commission_id = commissions.job_id 
WHERE proposals.proposal_id = '123'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like p.Salmon said in the comments, I would add a new column to the jobs table

```
ALTER TABLE Jobs add autoid INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```